# Attach a 5-star widget to a custom form

Tags: 7, rating

How do you add a [FiveStar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) widget to a (non-node) form using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'fivestar');      
  drupal_add_js($path . '/js/fivestar.js');
  drupal_add_css($path . '/css/fivestar.css');

  $rating = votingapi_select_single_result_value(array(
        'entity_id' => YOURENTITY_ID,
        'entity_type' => 'YOURENTITY_TYPE',
        'tag' => 'vote',
        'function' => 'average',
   ));
   $form['votes'] = array(
      '#markup' =>  theme('fivestar_static', array('rating' => $rating, 'stars' => 5, 'tag' => 'vote')),
   );
```

Comment: This loads the 5 stars, but the required CSS and JavaScript are not loaded.

Comment: Code is changed due to last comment.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using the following code.

```
$form['presentation_ratting'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fivestar',
  '#stars' => 5,
  '#title' => t('Presentation.'),
);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please avoid code-only answers and add a bit of explanation why and how this code would work.

Comment: This works for me. THX !

Comment: Working fine I need one thing more. How can I add default value?